# Как запретить отправку формы, если в сообщении есть ссылка?

Tags: javascript, html

Как запретить отправку ссылок в форме.
Например, ввёл в поле сообщение со ссылкой - скрипт запрещает отправку т.к. есть ссылка.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Нет смысла блокировать скриптом — юзер может в любой момент отключить javascript и обойти контроль. Проверяйте на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Например можно вот так:

```html
<script>
  function checkForm(form) {
    if (form.user_text.value.match(/.+\.\w\w.*/gi)) {
      alert("Никаких ссылок в сообщении");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
  <textarea name="user_text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

P.S. Но так как JS может быть отключен, то необходима так же проверка и на сервере.